# NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

rails newbie here. I'm on the last section of the tutorial and I just can't believe I get stuck here.

I get a noMethodError in static_pages_controller that says this

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x3c22aa0>
```

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

I have the will_paginate gem installed and the paginate function works on the other parts of the code.

I'm on Michael Hartl Rails tutorial section 11.3.4.

It would be great if you guys could help me out.

Comment: Could you please explain method of `feed`

Comment: def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end                                           It basically shows all the microposts from the users you follow.

Comment: However that is solved. I however have a problem with undefined method `id' This is the method where the error comes from           <li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
2:   <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
3:     <span class="user">
4:       <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>

Answer (score 2):

`will_paginate` by default does not support pagination for arrays.  in order to support this, you need to require an additional file. create a file called `will_paginate_array.rb` inside `config/initializers`.  then add the following

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

restart your server and you should be able to paginate arrays.

Comment: However I got another error from ruby undefined method `id' for #<String:0x6082350>  This is the code for it

Comment: <li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>

Comment: sorry, i'm not familiar with the tutorial.  i can only infer that `feed_item` is a string if the error points to the first part of the code.